# Хранение большого текста в Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Есть потребность хранить отчет в html в виде текста в БД (нет других способов больше), состоит она из 400 000 символов(или 5мб). Используется БД Postgres. Так вот, какой способ лучше. Если хранить как текст или массив байт, то при количестве строк в таблице, она становится трудоемкая на загрузку, это логично.
Но если например хранить в виде CLOB или BLOB, то это некая ссылка на таблицу pg_largeobject, где этот объект разбивается на части по 2048 байт. Вроде бы все ок и таблица грузится за милисекунды и все вроде бы классно. Но вопрос в том, что таблица pg_largeobject забивается, и если запись удалить из основной, то из pg_largeobject записи не удаляются, и тут я не понимаю, как лучше ее очищать(возможно триггер), сколько она может заполняться, потому что я так понял там loid последовательность не обнуляется и когда-то должна закончиться.

Знающие и сталкивающиеся с такой задачкой люди, помогите советом пожалуйста. Как лучше поступить с хранением. Ограничен во всем, есть только БД.
Так-то бы конечно хранил в виде файла на диске, а в бд чисто ссылку на него, но нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для удаления объекта по триггеру выполняйте [lo_unlink](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/14/lo-interfaces#LO-UNLINK) или [lo_manage](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/14/lo#id-1.11.7.33.6) или переодически выполняйте [vacuumlo](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/14/vacuumlo) для очистки потерянных объектов.

loid не закончится к выходу на пенсию

Comment: loid не закончится к выходу на пенсию - мне нравится такой ответ))) а можно узнать максимальное значение, это так, для себя) а то что-то я нигде не могу найти ответа.

Comment: на самом деле не такое большое число 4294967296 - loid это oid, а oid занимает 4 байта. думаю что настанет время горизонтального масштабирования раньше чем наступит этот лимит. с вашими файлами это 20480 терабайт.

Comment: Спасибо большое